# How do you print out multiple graphs of data from an arduino power monitor?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, arduino

I'm confused about how you set up the code to read three separate readings into matplotlib graphs in python and the timing between the Python and Arduino code.

Arduino code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_INA260.h>

Adafruit_INA260 ina260 = Adafruit_INA260();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Wait until serial port is opened
  while (!Serial) { delay(10); }

 // Serial.println("Adafruit INA260 Test");

  if (!ina260.begin()) {
    //Serial.println("Couldn't find INA260 chip");
    while (1);
  }
  //Serial.println("Found INA260 chip");
}

void loop() {
  //Serial.print("Current: ");
  Serial.println(ina260.readCurrent());
 // Serial.println(" mA");

 // Serial.print("Bus Voltage: ");
  Serial.println(ina260.readBusVoltage());
  
//  Serial.println(" mV");

 // Serial.print("Power: ");
  Serial.println(ina260.readPower());
 // Serial.println(" mW");


  delay(1000);
}
```

Python code

```
import serial
import time
import glob
import csv
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("tkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate = 115200, timeout = 5)
ser.flushInput()

plot_window = 20
y_current = np.array(np.zeros([plot_window]))
y_voltage = np.array(np.zeros([plot_window]))
y_power = np.array(np.zeros([plot_window]))

plt.ion()
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3)
lineC, = ax1.plot(y_current)
lineV, = ax2.plot(y_voltage)
lineP, = ax3.plot(y_power)

while True:
    try:
        current_bytes = ser.readline()
        voltage_bytes = ser.readline()
        power_bytes = ser.readline()
        try:
            decoded_current = float(current_bytes[0:len(current_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8").rstrip())
            decoded_voltage = float(voltage_bytes[0:len(voltage_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8").rstrip())
            decoded_power = float(power_bytes[0:len(power_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8").rstrip())
            print(decoded_current + " mA " + decoded_voltage + " mV " + decoded_power + " mW ")
        except:
            continue
#        with open("test_data.csv","a") as f:
#            writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
#            writer.writerow([time.time(),decoded_bytes])
        y_current = np.append(y_current,decoded_current)
        y_current = y_current[1:plot_window+1]
        lineC.set_ydata(y_current)
        
        y_voltage = np.append(y_voltage,decoded_voltage)
        y_voltage = y_voltage[1:plot_window+1]
        lineV.set_ydata(y_voltage)
        
        y_power = np.append(y_power,decoded_power)
        y_power= y_power[1:plot_window+1]
        lineP.set_ydata(y_power)
        
        ax1.relim()
        ax1.autoscale_view()
        
        ax2.relim()
        ax2.autoscale_view()
        
        ax3.relim()
        ax3.autoscale_view()
        
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
    except:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")
        break
```

I am able to get the python code to successfully graph the data if I only track a singular power measurement, I'm just not sure how to do it for multiple data readings.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using arrays for your data, one new array for each type of measurement (looks like you have that so far). So, when a new datapoint comes in, push it onto its array. When you go to set your data, you'll use the arrays to graph more points (and it looks like you're doing that, too).

I think the problem is with the set_ydata call; I found this Stack Overflow answer that describes in more detail what "set_ydata" and "set_data" are, and how to use them.

[[matplotlib]: understanding "set_ydata" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208678/matplotlib-understanding-set-ydata-method)

This stack Overflow answer shows how to graph multiple lines--and animate them. That sounds like fun, and it has a clear code example too:
[Defining multiple plot objects in an array and updating in matplotlib animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515563/defining-multiple-plot-objects-in-an-array-and-updating-in-matplotlib-animation)